# Hi, i'd like to have an array of Toasts in a separate class.

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-intent, android-activity

i'd like to have an array of Toasts in a separate class. Can anyone please with it..i'm having a confusion as to what data type does the array have to be.

any code please? please note i wish base this area in a new class and i'll be needing it during onClick to get the required toast from the array.

Comment: Could you clarifiy your question and show what have you tried so far?

Comment: Do you mean the entire toast or just the message itself? The messages could just be in a CharSequence/string array.

Comment: could you show it in code? just an array with 2 to 3 elements will do @BenjaminS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just an idea, but you could keep the messages themselves in a List or array, and pass that when building your toast.

```
String[] sArray = new String[2];
sArray[0] = "TestMessage1";
sArray[1] = "TestMessage2"

Toast.makeText(appContext, sArray[0], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Using a separate method you could do something like:

```
public class newClass{
        public static String getToastMessage(int messagenum){
        return sArray[messagenum];
   }    
}

Toast.makeText(appContext, newClass.getToastMessage(0), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

This is a bit pseudo-cody but is this along the lines of what you're looking for?